# what is the easiest way to show $-1$ is quadratic residue modulo $p=4k+1$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

what is the easiest way to show $-1$ is quadratic residue modulo prime $p=4k+1$?

Is there a better way than showing $(2k)!^2\equiv -1 \mod p$?

Comment: Showing what? How is that related? Anyway, if you know basic group theory that can make things easier.

Comment: This depends on your taste. I find it best to use $(-1/p)=(-1)^{\frac{p-1}{2}}=1$ for $p\equiv 1(4)$.

Comment: then $x^2\equiv-1\modp$ has a solution.

Comment: But J.A. IMHO that is one of the better ways of doing it! My freshman algebra students agreed. It is much easier than proving that $\Bbb{Z}_p^*$ is cyclic.

Comment: But that's exactly, or even much harder, than solving $\;x^2=-1\pmod p\;$ , isn't it?

Comment: Whom are you addressing, @JyrkiLahtonen ?

Comment: No, I use the formula for $p=4k+1$, so I get $(-1/p)=(-1)^{2k}=1$, which means quadratic residue.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen if you use $\mathbb Z_p$ is cyclic, it comes down to showing $(2k)!^2\equiv -1\mod p$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I made wrong objection. In my opinion Euler's criterion still uses a form of $(2k)!^2\equiv-1\mod p$ since it uses cyclic group property that Jykri suggests.

Comment: Euler's criterion uses only that $\mathbb{Z}/p$ has no zero divisors: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_criterion.

Comment: For any $a$ between $1$ and $p-1$, there is a unique $b$ in the same interval such that $ab\equiv -1\pmod{p}$. If for all $a$ we have $b\ne a$, then $(p-1)!\equiv (-1)^{(p-1)/2}\equiv 1\pmod{p}$, contradicting Wilson's Theorem.

Comment: Damn it! I am NOT suggesting that you use cyclicity of $\Bbb{Z}_p^*$. It is MUCH simpler to prove that $(2k!)^2\equiv-1$ using Wilson's theorem.

Answer (score 1):

The multiplicative group $\;\Bbb F_p^*\;$ is cyclic and$\;\left|\Bbb F_p^*\right|=p-1\;$, and since $\;p-1\;$ is divisible by $\;4\;$ there exists one unique subgroup of order $\;4\;$, say $\;H=\langle x\rangle=\{1,x,x^2,x^3\}\;$ , and since $\;x^2\neq 1\;$ but $\;(-1)^2=1\;$ , we must have $\;x^2=-1\;$ and we're done.

Comment: This is a variation of the same theme as $(2k)!^2\equiv-1\mod p$ Both use cyclic property of the group.

Comment: I've no idea what how that odd-looking $\;(2k)!^2\;$ thing relates to the above quick, non-messy proof with basic group theory.

Comment: ok thinking again, you have a point since you do not use the full $\mathbb Z_p$ as others You cleverly, use a subgroup.

Comment: But are you sure the existence of subgroup of order $4$, invokes no property of the full cyclic group? How do you know the subgroup is cyclic and generated by $x$?

Comment: Apparently you mean by "full cyclic group" the **additive** group of residues modulo $\;p\;$, namely $\;\Bbb F_p\;$ . In the above I use the **multiplicative** group of that field, $\;\Bbb F_p^*:=\Bbb F_p\setminus\{0\}\;$, and use that *any* finite subgroup of the multiplicative group of **any** field is cyclic.

Comment: I mean the multiplicative group. I like your proof. But just two points $1)$ does existence of order $4$ subgroup uses the multiplicative order of the bigger group? $2)$ how do you know the order $4$ subgroup is cyclic?

Comment: Read my last comment, @J.A ! Every subgroup of a cyclic group is cyclic, for example...and any such cyclic *finite* group has one unique subgroup of **any** order dividing the group's order. All this is basic group theory.

Comment: ok how about point $1$, does the existence use the multiplicative order of the bigger group like euler criterion?

Comment: I know. But I do not want the 'long' proof of unrolling the group as in euler criterion. Your proof is short. In a computational sense.

Comment: The existence of a subgroup of order four follows from the fact that the **multiplicative** group of the field has order a multiple of four...and from the second point in my last comment.

Comment: ok so it is in a sense a very morphed version euler criterion.

Comment: @J.A, **Everything** in mathematics is a morphed version of something else, most probably Euler's, Gauss's, Cauchy's or someone like these ones.

Comment: No actually in cs there is a theorem which states if we can prove the above without unrolling the group, we can break many cryptosystems.

Comment: I can't say, @J.A , but if cs is computer science I doubt greatly there's a theorem involving groups in that. Of course, I've no idea what "unrolling the group" can possibly mean.

Answer (score 1):

It is IMHO the easiest way:
$$
\begin{aligned}
(2k)!^2&=(1\cdot2\cdot3\cdots 2k)(1\cdot2\cdot3\cdots 2k)\\
&=(1\cdot2\cdot3\cdots 2k)(1\cdot2\cdot3\cdots 2k)(-1)^{2k}\\
&=(1\cdot2\cdot3\cdots 2k)(-1)\cdot(-2)\cdot(-3)\cdots(-2k)\\
&\equiv(1\cdot2\cdot3\cdots 2k)(4k)(4k-1)(4k-2)\cdots(2k+1)\\
&=(4k)!\\
&\equiv-1,
\end{aligned}
$$
where in the last step we use Wilson's theorem. No need to spend any time proving cyclicity :-)

Comment: I think with group theory is faster and no need to spend any time proving Wilson's theorem (which, btw, is many times proved by means of group theory)

Comment: IMO it depends, @Timbuc. If you are going to prove cyclicity during the ongoing course, then I agree with you. Wilson does use pairing up residue classes and their inverses. If cyclicity is postponed to the next course as is the case where I teach, then the eager students appreciated this way.

Comment: I do appreciate it, @Jyrki: it is a nice way to prove it, yet the OP apparently wanted something else, though now I'm not so sure about that any more.